# How does angular material autogenerate it's API documentaion?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I noticed that Angular Material (https://github.com/angular/components) generates parts of it's docs from code comments, for example here: https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/api.
How do they do this? 
And is the rest of the documentation just hardcoded or built dynamically in a "magical" way?

Cheers Tobi

Comment: Most likely https://jsdoc.app/ or http://typedoc.org/ with their own custom theme

Answer (score 0):

there are tools that can help with these kind of tasks. 
You could use [compodoc](https://compodoc.app/guides/getting-started.html),

> Compodoc is a documentation tool for Angular applications. It
>   generates a static documentation of your application.

You need to describe the fuction as follows:

/**

- @param {string} target  The target to process
- @returns The processed target number

*/

function processTarget(target:string):number {};

Comment: Hey, yeah I know compodoc and typedoc, but they don't add annotations for everything. It seems more like they autoparse components somehow. My problem is couldn't find their config in the code, when I tried to replicate their docs.